# Error in getting value of first row from the table in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, combobox

I'm new to ExtJS. So finding little difficult in understanding many things.

I've a sample combo box where I'm retrieving datas from the table

This is the combo box:

```
xtype: 'fieldset',
    title: 'Dress Type',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'combobox',
        name: 'dresses',
        forceNewStore: true,
        queryMode: 'local',
        displayField: "description",
        valueField: "description",
        mapperId: 'getavailabletype',
        emptyText: 'Select Type
        forceSelection: true,
        maskRe: /[A-Za-z0-9]/,
        margin: '15px',
        allowBlank: false,
        triggers: {
            clear: {
                cls: 'x-form-clear-trigger',
                handler: function() {
                    this.reset();
                }
            }
        },
    }]
```

Here is the way I'm trying to retain the first value of the table:
    `me.down("combobox[name=dresses]").setValue(me.down("combobox[name=dresses]").store.getAt('0').get('description'));`

I'm getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of null **@getAt('0')**

Please help

Comment: Which version of ExtJs are you using?

Comment: version 4.. I was using static store and now i replaced it with a data from the database. don't know how to populate the default .

Comment: Usually the first value of table is the first record of store...

Comment: I mean, you can use store.first() method

Comment: Where are you trying to using this `me.down("combobox[name=dresses]").setValue(me.down("combobox[name=dresses]").store.getAt('0').get('description'));`

Comment: @UDID in the listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know from what listener and component you are trying to achieve this, but from my perspective, the best place to achieve this is in the "render" event listener of the combobox.

Like so:

```
listeners: {
    'render': function(combo) {
        combo.setValue(combo.getStore().first());
    }
}
```

Here you have a working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qqk

**OR**

If you have a reference to the combo store, let's say it's in the *comboStore* variable, you can set the first value like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    value: comboStore.first()
}
```

Another fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qql

**Now, if you are not sure that the store will be loaded by the time you initialize your combo**, you can set the following listener for the combobox:

```
listeners: {
    render: function(combo) {
        var store = combo.getStore(),
            setFirstStoreValFn = function() {
                combo.setValue(store.first());
            };

        if (store.getCount()) {
            setFirstStoreValFn();
        }
        else {
            store.on('load', setFirstStoreValFn, null, {single: true})
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, it creates a reusable function that sets the combo value to the first record in the store, and then it checks if the store has records (which means that is has been loaded) it will call the function, if not - it will set a single load listener on the store which will then call the set value function.

Again, the fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qqm

Answer (score 0):

you need to navigate to cmp --> store --> first record ---> data

for that `me.down("combobox[name=dresses]").store.getAt(0).get('d‌​escription'))`